# How can I manage to get a button with a custom.id to work in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a bot to play a game with my friend and I want the bot to create buttons for as many player as there are. So my goal is that every button got a custom id corresponding to the player so that the bot can know which button has been clicked.
But even after setting up my `custom_id` in the button parameters, the `interaction.id` is still a long int variable that changes every time the button is clicked.

Of course this doesn't work but this is what my code looks like for the moment

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def Report(ctx):
        players=list(player_list.values())
        view = Report_Buttons()

        for i in players:
            boutton=discord.ui.Button(style=ButtonStyle.danger, label=str(i[1]), disabled=False, custom_id="Filou")
            view.add_item(boutton)
            
        await ctx.send(view = view)
        async def filou(interaction : discord.Interaction):
                
            print(interaction.id)            
            if "Filou" == interaction.id:
                await ctx.send("The button has been clicked")
    
        boutton.callback = filou
```

Comment: You are comparing a `custom_id` to an `interaction.id` which does not work out.

Comment: yes I understood that but can I find a way to know which button is clicked thanks to the interaction.id or the custom.id ?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find a workaround, I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works for what i want to do. I've seen many of you edited my answer for it to match the good form on the forum. Forgive me if it's poorly presented I'm still new to this site and don't know how to use it well.

==============================================

Anyways my solution is :

```
async def filou(interaction : discord.Interaction):
   if list(interaction.data.values())[0]=="Filou":  

#I am checking here in the data.values the custom_id that was used to make the interaction which is "Filou" in my button

      await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button with the following custom_id :  Filou") 
   else:
      await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked another Button")
```

I hope this will save time to someone struggling like I did

Comment: Would be better to use the dictionary straight from `interaction.data` but overall a perfect solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to change

```
list(interaction.data.values())[0]=="Filou"
```

To

```
interaction.data['custom_id'] == "Filou"
```

Full code in your case:

```
async def filou(interaction : discord.Interaction):
   if interaction.data['custom_id'] == "Filou": 
      await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button with the following custom_id :  Filou") 
   else:
      await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked another Button")
```